# Base.repeat for numerical arrays vs. Base.kron

Tags: arrays, julia, repeat

I recently came across extending some of the numerical arrays that I work with along different axes and in different orders, and the `repeat` function of Base using `inner` and `outer` came quite handy. However, it seems like the `kron` function is extremely faster and more memory efficient. Is there any way that a more general function like `repeat` use this functionality. I understand that the repeat is not limited to numerical arrays, but wouldn't it make sense to use this functionality?

```
function inner_repeat(
    X::AbstractArray{T, 2},
    K::Int64,
) where {T <: AbstractFloat}
    return repeat(X, inner = (K, 1))
end


function inner_kron_repeat(
    X::AbstractArray{T, 2},
    K::Int64,
) where {T <: AbstractFloat}
    return kron(X, ones(T, K, 1))
end


Xs = [rand(10^i, 10^i) for i in 2:4]
Ks = [i for i in 2:4]

for X in Xs
    for K in Ks
        println("matrix of size $(size(X)) with $(K) repeats")
        println("using repeat:")
        @btime inner_repeat($X, $K)
        println("using kron:")
        @btime inner_kron_repeat($X, $K)
        println()
    end
end
```

And the output results are as follows:

```
matrix of size (100, 100) with 2 repeats
using repeat:
933.659 μs (50003 allocations: 1.68 MiB)
using kron:
  18.834 μs (3 allocations: 156.42 KiB)

matrix of size (100, 100) with 3 repeats
using repeat:
  966.348 μs (50003 allocations: 1.75 MiB)
using kron:
  21.505 μs (3 allocations: 234.56 KiB)

matrix of size (100, 100) with 4 repeats
using repeat:
  996.305 μs (50003 allocations: 1.83 MiB)
using kron:
  25.571 μs (3 allocations: 312.69 KiB)

matrix of size (1000, 1000) with 2 repeats
using repeat:
  111.865 ms (5000003 allocations: 167.85 MiB)
using kron:
  1.907 ms (3 allocations: 15.26 MiB)

matrix of size (1000, 1000) with 3 repeats
using repeat:
  117.833 ms (5000003 allocations: 175.48 MiB)
using kron:
  2.322 ms (3 allocations: 22.89 MiB)

matrix of size (1000, 1000) with 4 repeats
using repeat:
  125.939 ms (5000003 allocations: 183.11 MiB)
using kron:
  2.770 ms (3 allocations: 30.52 MiB)

matrix of size (10000, 10000) with 2 repeats
using repeat:
  12.320 s (500000003 allocations: 16.39 GiB)
using kron:
  631.530 ms (3 allocations: 1.49 GiB)

matrix of size (10000, 10000) with 3 repeats
using repeat:
  12.887 s (500000003 allocations: 17.14 GiB)
using kron:
  862.406 ms (3 allocations: 2.24 GiB)

matrix of size (10000, 10000) with 4 repeats
using repeat:
  13.406 s (500000003 allocations: 17.88 GiB)
using kron:
  1.098 s (3 allocations: 2.98 GiB)
```

Comment: In general <code>kron</code> is not equivalent to <code>repeat</code>, but is only equivalent to a few very special cases of repeat. It might be worth doing a performance PR for the specific case of repeat with inner specified, outer not specified, and inner with two parameters, the second one == 1.